# bootstrap 4 display flex example not working

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a psd like this and I want to design like this.

[image: psd]

But I see this demo

[image: demo]

```
<div class="col-6">
    <div class="media border-2 border-secondary border-solid p-1">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
            <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/51/f6/fb/51f6fb256629fc755b8870c801092942.jpg" class="mr-1 rounded-circle w-25 h-25">
            <div class="media-body">
                <span class="h5 mr-2">رضا امیری</span>
                <span class="small">5 روز پیش</span>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="/uploads/images/arrow-left.png">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="border-top">
            <p>آدرس: خیابان تختی</p>
            <a class="bg-primary" href="#">نقشه</a>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
            <div>
                <a href="#">امتیاز مشتریان: 2 تا </a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#">55000 تومان</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Whatever I thought, How this is done, I don't know.

I am creating a simple Express web server that serves a landing page made with bootstrap, but I can't get any Flexbox examples to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Bootstrap, start with a container and build up a series of rows and columns, adding padding and margin as needed to get the spacing you want.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rtlcss.com/bootstrap/v4.5.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<style>
    .rounded-1rem {
        border-radius: 1rem;
    }

    .icon-link {
        color: rgba(0,0,0,0.60);
    }

    .icon-link:hover {
        color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87);
    }

    .bg-light-gray {
        color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87);
        background-color: #C4C4C4;
    }
</style>

<div class="container-fluid" dir="rtl">
    <div class="row justify-content-center mt-5">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 px-3 border rounded-1rem">
            <div class="row no-gutters py-3">
                <div class="col-3">
                    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/51/f6/fb/51f6fb256629fc755b8870c801092942.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                </div>
                <div class="col-8 pl-3">
                    <div class="row pb-3">
                        <div class="col">
                            <span class="h5">رضا امیری</span>
                            <span class="small">5 روز پیش</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <a href="#" class="link-secondary icon-link pl-1"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></a>
                            <a href="#" class="link-secondary icon-link pl-1"><i class="fas fa-comment-dots"></i></a>
                            <a href="#" class="link-secondary icon-link pl-1"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1 text-right">
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-arrow-left fa-lg text-dark"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row no-gutters pb-3">
                <div class="col border-top pt-3">
                    <div class="">
                        <p>آدرس: خیابان تختی</p>
                        <a class="btn bg-light-gray" href="#"><i class="fas fa-map fa-sm"></i> نقشه </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row no-gutters pb-3">
                <div class="col border-top pt-3">
                    <a href="#" class="float-left">امتیاز مشتریان: 2 تا </a>
                    <a href="#" class="float-right">55000 تومان</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I didn't see anything that would need flex to control the positioning. I did use `float-left` and `float-right` in the last section to get the text on the left and right side. You could use flex to do that, but floats seemed easier.

I used [Bootstrap RTL](https://bootstrap.rtlcss.com/) rather than standard Bootstrap to support the right-to-left layout. If you don't need to support Internet Explorer, you may want to consider using Bootstrap 5, which has [RTL](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/rtl/) support as standard.